# In Wpf how do I send a command from a button to a child control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have a zoom-in-button placed in a menu bar, and several levels down there is a control I would like to have take the zoom in command and zoom in on the object being viewed and redraw.

As I understand from my reading, command normally bubble up with a preview event from the commandsource (in this case the button), and then tunnel back down to the command source, looking for a command binding that binds the command to the event handlers for the command. However, in my case, the control that I want to affect is levels down from the button.

Is it correct just having the binding be in a higher level control that gets hit, and then have that higher level control run the methods on the lower level function?

I thought it might look cleaner to just have the code set a command target onto the child descendant, but now i'm not sure if that is what command target actually does.

Can I just place command target like so:

```
CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=wavegraphcanvas, Path=CommandTarget, Mode=OneWay}"
```

in the xaml and have it find the element in its children?*

I thought what would happen is that it would bubble up from the button and then tunnel down till it found the element name or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CommandTarget` is appropriate when you know what element is the target.  In your case that seems to be true.

If you have multiple elements that can receive the command  (for example, 3 text boxes getting the `Paste` command) then it doesn't make sense to set the `CommandTarget`.  That's what the routing  part of the `RoutedCommand` does; attempt to find the appropriate element to apply the command,

Comment: yeah, if that's the case, then i don't know where my bug is, I just wanted to be sure that what I was trying to do was indeed possible.